# How to display nested json using tpl in extjs4

Tags: php, json, yii, extjs4, nested

i am working in extjs4 + yii framework. My server side is in yii[php] and client side is in extjs4. i am sending data from server side in json format.
i have json as-

```
{
    "data": {
        "Meaning": [
            {
                "Noun": "sea"
            },
            {
                "Adverb": "Null"
            },
            {
                "Adjective": "Null"
            }
        ],
        "pronunciation": "sea",
        "Media": [
            {
                "image": "abc.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "xyz.jpg"
            },
            {
                "Video": "Windows Media Audio/Video file (.wmv)"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i want to display this json on view of extjs using tpl. So how to display this nested json using extjs tpl?

Comment: Have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253118/extjs-parsing-nested-json-in-template

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
Ext.widget('panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    // 4 is the number of indentation spaces
    ,tpl: '<pre>{[JSON.stringify(values, null, 4)]}</pre>'
    ,height: 400
    ,data: ... // sample data
});
```